# Print column of array of objects as comma-separated string with no trailing comma

Tags: php, string, object, implode, array-column

I have the following code in html:

```
<? foreach($tst as $test) : ?>
    <?=$test->id?>,
<? endforeach ?>
```

and that will result
as `test1,test2,test3,`

How avoid that last comma in simple method. I can't use complicated code in html like:

```
<? $i = 0; ?>
<? foreach($tst as $test) : ?>
    <?= $test->id ?>,
<? endforeach ?>
<? $i++; ?>
<? if($i != count($tst)) :?>
    ,
<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why are you doing it like this? Why dont you write the for loop in php and simply echo the HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `implode` on an interim array:

```
<?php

$a= array();

foreach($tst as $test) {
 $a[]= $test->id;
}

echo(implode(', ', $a));

?>
```